# Bounding the minimum singular value of a block triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, singular-values

### Question:

What is the sharpest known lower bound for the minimum singular value of the block triangular matrix
$$M:=\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ 0 & D
\end{bmatrix}$$
in terms of the properties of its constituent matrices?

### Motivation:

- Block triangular matrices are ubiquitous in numerical linear algebra, and the minimum singular value is a basic property of any matrix. So, it would be useful to have a canonical answer to this question in an easily searchable place on the internet.
- A matrix of this form came up in my research on numerical methods, and I need to estimate its minimum singular value in order to understand the stability of a method I'm working on.

### My bound:

I was able to come up with the bounds
$$\boxed{\frac{1}{\sigma_\text{min}(M)} \le \sqrt{\left\Vert A^{-1}\right\Vert^2\left(1 + \left\Vert BD^{-1} \right\Vert^2 \right) + \left\Vert D^{-1} \right\Vert^2}}$$
and
$$\boxed{\frac{1}{\sigma_\text{min}(M)} \le \sqrt{\left\Vert D^{-1}\right\Vert^2\left(1 + \left\Vert A^{-1}B \right\Vert^2 \right) + \left\Vert A^{-1} \right\Vert^2}.}$$
using the following argument (for the first bound, the second one is the same argument but on the transpose):

The minimum singular value of a matrix is the inverse of the norm of the inverse matrix:
$$\frac{1}{\sigma_\text{min}(M)} = \left\Vert M^{-1} \right\Vert.$$
But inverse of a block triangular matrix has the following [exact formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1377703/3060):
$$M^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
A^{-1} & -A^{-1}BD^{-1} \\
0 & D^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Estimating the norm of the inverse directly from the definition and using the submultiplicative property of norms yields the boxed bound above:
\begin{align*}
\left\Vert M^{-1} \right\Vert^2 &= \sup_{||u||^2+||v||^2=1} \left\Vert \begin{bmatrix}
A^{-1} & -A^{-1}BD^{-1} \\
0 & D^{-1}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}u \\ v\end{bmatrix} \right\Vert^2 \\
&= \sup_{||u||^2+||v||^2=1} \left\Vert A^{-1} u - A^{-1}BD^{-1}v \right\Vert^2 + \left\Vert D^{-1} v\right\Vert^2 \\
&\le \left\Vert A^{-1}\right\Vert^2 \left\Vert\begin{bmatrix}I & -BD^{-1}\end{bmatrix}\right\Vert^2 + \left\Vert D^{-1} \right\Vert^2 \\
&= \left\Vert A^{-1}\right\Vert^2\left(1 + \left\Vert BD^{-1} \right\Vert^2 \right) + \left\Vert D^{-1} \right\Vert^2.
\end{align*}

### Conjectured bound:

The obvious conjecture based on the two bounds above is the following symmetrized version:
$$\frac{1}{\sigma_\text{min}(M)} \overset{?}{\le} \sqrt{\left\Vert D^{-1} \right\Vert^2 + \left\Vert A^{-1}BD^{-1} \right\Vert ^2 + \left\Vert A^{-1} \right\Vert ^2},$$
which I have been unable to prove.

If one applies the triangle inequality to the blocks of $M^{-1}$, one gets the similar looking bound:
$$\frac{1}{\sigma_\text{min}(M)} \le \left\Vert D^{-1} \right\Vert + \left\Vert A^{-1}BD^{-1} \right\Vert + \left\Vert A^{-1} \right\Vert,$$
but this is strictly worse than the conjectured bound since it is a sum rather than the square root of a sum of squares.

### Edit:

After getting no answers here, I [posted on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265887/bounding-the-minimum-singular-value-of-a-block-triangular-matrix), where it was answered. The conjectured bound is true.