# Inverse of a lower triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I got the following question to solve:

Given the lower triangular matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
    A_{11} & 0 \\
    A_{21} & A_{22}
  \end{bmatrix}

of size $n \times n$ (n is a power of 2) where $A_{11}$, $A_{21}$ and $A_{22}$ are matrices of size $(n/2) \times (n/2)$, show that the inverse is,

\begin{bmatrix}
    A_{11}^{-1} & 0 \\
    -A_{22}^{-1}A_{21}A_{11} & A_{22}^{-1}
  \end{bmatrix}

how do I go about to solve this problem?

Edit: the matrix is invertible.

Edit: the second matrix should be changed to:
\begin{bmatrix}
    A_{11}^{-1} & 0 \\
    -A_{22}^{-1}A_{21}A_{11}^{\color{red}{-1}} & A_{22}^{-1}
  \end{bmatrix}
The inverse was missing.

Comment: @Insertnamehere it feels like it's a problem for induction. n=2 I verified. But I have no idea how to go about the induction step.

Comment: Perhaps start [at Wikipedia's page on Block Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix).

Comment: You can derive the invese from the fact that $\begin{bmatrix}I \\ X & I\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}I \\ -X & I\end{bmatrix}$, as explained in my answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377634/inverse-of-partitioned-matrices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, you are having some trouble evaluating, and I think this is because of a typo! Evaluating with normal matrix multiplication I got
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & 0 \\
A_{21} & A_{22}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11}^{-1} & 0 \\
-A_{22}^{-1}A_{21}A_{11} & A_{22}^{-1}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
A_{11}A_{11}^{-1} & 0 \\
A_{21} A_{11}^{-1} -A_{22}A_{22}^{-1}A_{21}A_{11} & A_{22}A_{22}^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Everything evaluates trivially except for this term
$$A_{21} A_{11}^{-1} - A_{21}A_{11}$$
Which clearly does not equal $0$ all the time.
Thus I believe there was a typo made here and that the $A_{11}$ at the end should be an $A_{11}^{-1}$, as then the above expression reduces to the identity matrix,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 \\
0 & I
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! That was my typo and was not in the original. The problem I was having was that I did not know how to evaluate block matrices. Now I've learned it.

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

Evaluate the following quantity$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    A_{11} & 0 \\
    A_{21} & A_{22}
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    A_{11}^{-1} & 0 \\
    -A_{22}^{-1}A_{21}A_{11}^{\color{red}{-1}} & A_{22}^{-1}
  \end{bmatrix} .$$

Remark:

As pointed out by Isaac Browne, there is indeed a typo in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry it's not clear to me. Since the elements are not single elements but rather matrices themselves, how do I evaluate it?

Comment: references for you: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlockMatrix.html

Comment: If you evaluate it, this does not evaluate to the identity matrix.

Comment: yes, you are right, there is indeed a typo.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that!